# Parse Push Notification Analytics

Tags: parse-platform

There's a way to retrive via REST API the amount of sent and open push from Parse?They provide that information in their own page:

[image]

However i want to show my clients that information and any other Parse provides on my own page

Regards

Comment: Sadly there are no public API methods to get any of the analytics information. You _could_ get the figures out though by executing the same calls as the webpage does though. If you're looking to do this I think the easiest way would be to pop open chrome or safari developer tools, and look at the APIs that the javascript on those pages call. You'll most likely need to embed your account credentials to fake a login, so be careful!

Comment: @rickerbh wow, so wired...it's very usefull information and very easy for them to provided it. It would be nice to have a way to retrive that info without having to look which calls they are doing. What is more, probably that isn't made via Javascript either. I will check it out, but i don't like much that approach

Comment: hi @MarBVI do you found some way to do this? I have the same problem right now!

Comment: Hi @Lücks...we finished tracking the Push notifications our selves. We send in the payload of the PushNotification the ID of the Push in our DB, so when the push is opened on the mobile devices, they notify our server via REST that the Push was opened, so we can create our own analytics. We still lack the amount of push sent by Parse, but until they provide that information, it's impossible to know it